# Encontrar array dentro de uma string?

Tags: php

Tenho uma coluna no banco que salva um texto livre, e junto é salvo alguns dados dentro de `[ ]` é encontrar apenas o que está dentro de `[ ]` nesta string para converte-la em um array.

Exemplo:

```
$texto = "Hoje fomos até São Paulo visitar o paciente, [236,AD-BF] e não foi possível chegar a um diagnóstico";
```

Gostaria de extrarir apenas o `[236,AD-BF]` e transforma-lo em array.

Tem alguma forma de se fazer?

```
$array = explode(',',$texto);
```

Comment: O engraçado que vejo aqui é as pessoas negativar sem ao menos deixar uma justificativa, seria bom eu saber o motivo para poder melhor onde errei, não sou contra negativar sou até favorável pois ajuda-nos a evoluir.

Comment: você só quer um solução para esse caso especifico ou quer uma coisa reutilizável para outras frases?

Comment: Mas o texto a extrair vem sempre dentro de `[]` ? Existe apenas sempre só um bloco de `[]` ?

Comment: Seria algo que fosse reutilizável para outras frases que contenham o mesmo padrão de string

Comment: O texto a ser extraido vem sempre dentro de `[ ]` e cada string terá apenas uma ocorrencia

Comment: De uma pesquisada na função `preg_split`, ele é uma das possíveis soluções

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capturar o que está dentro de `[` e `]` é simples de fazer com uma regex como:

```
\[(.*)\]
```

Explicação:

```
\[   - Apanhar o caratere literal [
(.*) - Capturar tudo o que vem a seguir
\]   - Até encontrar o caratere literal ]
```

[Veja no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/27fzJ7/1)

Isto dá lhe o texto dentro de `[` e `]`. Com este texto basta usar explode com `","` para ficar com o array desejado.

Exemplo:

```
$texto = "Hoje fomos até São Paulo visitar o paciente, [236,AD-BF] e não foi possível chegar a um diagnóstico";
preg_match("/\[(.*)\]/", $texto, $capturado);

$array = explode(",", $capturado[1]);
print_r($array);
```

[Veja a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bJ1out)

Para a captura com a regex utilizei função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php), que devolve o primeiro grupo de captura na posicao `1`, que explica o parametro `$capturado[1]`.

Comment: Estava atrás de um explicação sobre a lógica do regex e com essa sua resposta o conceito ficou bem mais claro. +1

Comment: Só uma observação , se for utilizado `$capturado[0]` vai ser retornado exatamente o resultado desejado:`[236,AD-BF]` , se utilizado ´print_r($array);` é retornado `Array ( [0] => 236 [1] => AD-BF )`

Comment: @ThiagoDrulla Na posição `0` tem o *match* completo, que vai incluir os `[` e `]` e que se vão ver no `explode`. [Veja o exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/XUCRtc)

Comment: Perfeita a explanação foi uma aula, e conceituou muito bem o meu problema, inclusive já consigo utiliza-lo em outras partes do sistema. Obrigado.

Comment: Só uma dica para otimizar ainda mais a ER. Adicione o ? apos *
'/\[(.*?)\]/' 
Com '/\[(.*?)\]/' 24 steps e '/\[(.*)\]/' 94 steps
Sobre os "steps"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447805/what-are-steps-in-regexbuddy